# Вопросы о прямой речи

Tags: прямая-речь

1. Предложения с прямой речью состоят из слов автора и прямой речи, которые объединяются между собой бессоюзной связью.
2. Прямая речь не может быть передана в виде диалога.
3. Косвенная речь — это дословно воспроизведённая чужая речь, которая на письме заключается в кавычки.
4. Цитата — это дословная выдержка (отрывок) из какого-либо текста с указанием автора или источника.
5. Эпиграф — это цитата, изречение, помещаемые автором перед своим произведением (или перед отдельной частью) и характеризующие его основную идею.
6. Прямая речь может состоять из одного, двух и более предложений.
7. Прямая речь используется только в научном и официально-деловом стилях.
8. Предложение с косвенной речью представляет собой простое осложнённое предложение.
9. Если цитата приводится не полностью, то на месте пропуска ставится многоточие.
10. Основная сфера использования цитат — устная разговорная речь.

Верны ли мои ответы?

1. да. 2. нет. 3. нет. 4. да. 5. да. 6. да. 7. нет. 8. да. 9. да. 10. нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все ответы верны, кроме пункта 8.

Предложение с косвенной речью представляет собой **сложное** (сложноподчинённое) предложение. Например:

*Она сказала, что придёт завтра.

Они говорят, что не смогут прийти, потому что заняты.*

> **Главная часть** таких предложений строится *от имени автора текста* и соответствует словам *автора при прямой речи*, а **придаточная часть** передает содержание *высказывания и соответствует прямой речи.*

См. [здесь](https://interneturok.ru/lesson/russian/8-klass/pryamaya-i-kosvennaya-rech/pryamaya-i-kosvennaya-rech-znaki-prepinaniya-v-predlozheniyah-s-pryamoy-rechyu).